# How to use outline materialize icons according to new theme for web?

Tags: icons, material-design, materialize

Materialize has categorized the icons in five formats:-

> Rounded,filled,outlined,two tone , Sharp.

Below is the link
https://material.io/tools/icons.

But all categories have same link for displaying icons(which will display default icon in previous version.). I can download png image and then use but this is not efficient way. I have searched a lot and not find anything? Does anybody have used it?

Answer (score 1):

No, currently there is no way to use it, even with modifying CSS or any other way proposed elsewhere. Until they provide instructions they're there only for the show.

Comment: feels same, we have to wait till they provide instruction

Answer (score 0):

Cant add comment...so asking same question in answer section.
I have same question and couldn't find solution. I agree, the usage of icon defaults to the original (filled) icon. I need to know if I want to use the outlined icon, how I can use it in code.